# Windows 10 built-in backup tool: Can't exclude Music, Videos & Pictures user folders

Tags: windows-10, backup, user-folders

Trying to setup the built-in Backup (File History) to make automatic copies of some important work files in my Windows 10 Pro. I do not need to backup such user folders as Music, Videos and Pictures using this tool, but I can't remove them from the backup settings. They are always returned to the list of folders to backup automatically!

Is there a way to prevent system from doing this?

Comment: Are navigating to those folders by going to C:\Users\TecMan\[Pictures, Videos, or Music]?

Comment: @Neil, what do you mean? If you mean paths, yes, the folder location is right. I try to remove the folders using the Remove button next to every folder, or even add them to the exclusion list -  but neither helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  Are you using the raw path of "c:\users\username\folder", or are you using the the pseudopath "libraries\folder".  Both ways should work; however 'should' != 'does' so this will eliminate a really easy variable right off the bat.

Comment: @Neil, i do not add those folders to the backup myself - the system does that automatically, and it uses the template "c:users\<username>\folder". How could it help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can exclude those folders from File History if we exclude whole libraries from the backup list. To do that, open the File History applet in the classic Control Panel and click the "Exclude folders" hyperlink:

[image]

The "Exclude folders" dialog allows us to exclude libraries but not only folders despite of its name:

[image]

Select the required libraries using the Add button in it.

Note that the Music, Videos, Pictures, Documents and similar folders from our libraries are still visible in the "Back up these folders" list in the new Settings (and you even can't remove them from that list), but they are not archived!